# how do I get emacs to treat a file with the wrong extension correctly?

Tags: emacs, file-type

So (let us not concern ourselves with why) I have a **.emacs** file which is called **dotemacs**, and a **.bashrc** file which is called **dotbashrc**.

When I load up **dotemacs**, I get no syntax highlighing (amongst other things). If I do **M-x lisp-mode** then all is well.

Without changing the name of the file, how do I get emacs to recognise automatically that **dotemacs** is a lisp file and go into **lisp-mode**? Similarly for bash scripts, and indeed any other type of file with the wrong (or no) extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put this at the top of the dotemacs file:

```
; -*- mode: lisp -*-
```

causing it to start elisp-mode when you load the file.

For shell scripts, putting a #!/bin/bash (for whichever shell you are using) is enough to turn on the correct mode.  Or otherwise put this at the top of the file:

```
# -*- mode: sh -*-
```

Comment: Emacs recognizing the shell command at the top of the file allows us to have 'extensionless' scripts without lowering programming productivity by always having to set the mode.

Answer (score 4):

I like the answer above, but here is another way you *could* do it :)

Add the following line to your .emacs

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '(".emacs" . lisp-mode))
```