# Recognize a file with a shebang and no extension

Tags: emacs, shebang

I know that emacs can recognize a file by the extension, a `-*- mode -*-` first line, and even by the [shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7519908/915501) line, but what do I do if I want to override the shebang?

For example, a script that starts with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
...
```

won't be recognized by the shebang line alone. I also can't add in a `-*-python-*-` line, because then the shell tries to parse it. How do I deal with this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You put the `-*- mode: python -*-` in the *second* line (special exception, added specifically for the shebang thingies).

Comment: this is _almost_ embarrassingly obvious.

Answer (score 9):

You can try putting something like

```
(add-to-list 'interpreter-mode-alist '("python2.7" . python-mode))
```

in your `.emacs`. See “[Choosing File Modes](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Choosing-Modes.html)” for more info.

Comment: I can't get this to work by pasting this line directly into my `.emacs` file. Do you expect something _like_ this to work, or should this work?

Comment: I didn’t test it, but I did some experiments and I think it should work. You need to restart Emacs or evaluate that line to apply the change.

Comment: This worked for me. I just had to evaluate it... naturally... since this is how all Emacs config works.

Comment: Great, no need to add extra/special lines to the file.  I needed this to open bash scrips in `sh-mode`: ``(add-to-list 'interpreter-mode-alist '("#!/bin/bash" . sh-mode))`` and found here how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

print "test"

# Local Variables:
# mode: python
# End:
```

This information comes from `Specifying File Variables` node of `info`.

1. Use <kbd>f1 i</kbd> to enter info.
2. Use <kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)` to jump to emacs info.
3. Use <kbd>g</kbd> `Specifying File Variables` to jump to the page.
   You can use <kbd>tab</kbd> to complete node names.

Comment: is the `print "test"` line needed?

Comment: print "test" isn't needed, of course, it's just some python code to make sure that font-lock is on. If this doesn't work, you need to upgrade your Emacs. The current version is 24.3

Comment: in what version of emacs was this added? I'm not sure if it's worth upgrading if I'm already running version where it should work. (I'm using 23.3)

Comment: Here's the link http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html. If this is not in your `info`, you don't have it.

Comment: if what is not in my info? What's my info?

Comment: it's there in my `info`, but I still can't get it working. Oddly a simple `-*- mode: python -*-` does the trick.